# “Gradle files have changed since last project sync.” message does not go away after changing date

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

I modified my PC's date(current date - 2) for some reason and after that I'm facing issues with the Gradle syncing process. No matters how many times I sync it the message

> Gradle files have changed since last project sync. A project sync
>   maybe necessary for IDE to work properly

pops up again and again. I have tried to apply other stack overflow solutions, i.e

> correcting my time,date and timezone, cleaning and rebuilding the
>   project and even deleting the files mentioned in .gitignore file
>   (which is present in the project root directory) the files I was able to found
>   and then building again, but to no avail. **Maybe I'm missing something while following the solutions.**

I'd really thankful if someone can help me in this matter.

[This is how I have adjusted my time and date.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHaiO.png)

This is my top level build.gradle file

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
  }
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
  }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And this is my app level build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.biji.riderapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.0.1'
  implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: It might not be your problem, have you tried 'invalid cache' ? or update those dependencies to latest version if possible.